# Double associative array or indexed + associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
apple
   color: red   
   price: 2

orange
   color: orange
   price: 3

banana
  color: yellow
   price: 2
```

When I get `input`, let's say `green apple` how do I check if it exists in the array and display its data (if it exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fruits = array(
    'apple' => array(
        'color' => 'green',
        'price' => 3
    ),
    'banana' => array(
        'color' => 'yelo',
        'price' => 2
    ),
);
```

That?

You can look up by name using `$fruits[$fruit_name];`

Comment: Why can't you ignore the color and just use the second word?